# JS String: Add whitespace between numbers and letters

Tags: javascript, regex, string

i need a regular expression or any other method to add whitespaces between numbers and letters in a string.

Example:

```
"E2356" => "E 2356"
"E123-F456" => "E 123-F 456"
```

I already found a regular expression capable of it but it is not possible with Javascript:

```
(?<=[^0-9])(?=[0-9])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Instead of a look-behind, just match the non-digit:

```
[^0-9](?=[0-9])
```

And replace with "$& ".

The `[^0-9]` subpattern will match 1 character that is not a digit that can be referenced with `$&` (the whole matched text) in the replacement pattern. `(?=[0-9])` lookahead will make sure there is a digit right after it.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gF6tT0/2)

```js
var re = /[^0-9](?=[0-9])/g; 
var str = 'E2356<br/>E123-F456';
var result = str.replace(re, '$& ');
document.write(result);
```

Comment: Sure, but what's the advantage in looking-ahead for the number when you can just match it instead?

Comment: BTW, now, `(?<=[^0-9])(?=[0-9])` works in Chrome, Opera, some other ECMAScript 2018 compliant browsers and Node.js.

Comment: Didn't work for '275LBS'

Comment: @LucioMollinedo It should not since you want to add spaces between digits and letters, not between letters and digits (as in this question). You might want `.replace(/(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)/g, ' ')` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zLAVne/1)).

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew good one. My head was a bit heated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Match the two-character sequence of letter followed by number, with capture groups for both the letter and number, then use `String#replace` with the `$1` and `$2` placeholders to refer to the content of the capture groups, with a space in between.

```
str.replace(/([^0-9])([0-9])/g, '$1 $2')
              ^^$1^^  ^^$2^
```

The `g` flag ensures all occurrences are replaced, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String#replace`:

```
'E123-F456'.replace(/([A-Z])(\d)/g, '$1 $2')
// >>> "E 123-F 456"
```

`$1` and `$2` are the captured groups from the regex and are separated by a space. The expression assumes you only have uppercase characters. Remember to add the `g` flag to your expression to replace every occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot format a string using regex. 
Regex helps you validate that whether a certain string follow the language described by expression.

Regex helps you capture certain parts of the string in different variables and then format them as you want to get the desired output.

So I would suggest you do something like this :

```
var data = "E2304" ; 
var regex = ([^0-9])([0-9]*)/g ; 
data.replace(/regex, '$1 $2') ;
```

Comment: Right, regexp cannot create or modify strings, they can only match. However it's common usage to say "I need a regexp to format this string" when what is actually meant is "I need a regexp to use in conjunction with `replace` or something to format this string", and pretty much everyone understands that shorthand.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code

```
var test = "E123-F456".match(/[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+/g);
console.log(test.join(' '));
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/anandgh/h2g8cnha/

Comment: This would seem to both destroy hyphens, and also put spaces in the wrong places, such as between a number followed by a letter. The result of your sample is `"E 123 F 456"`.